# css div height setting to zero

Tags: css

I have a problem hidding a DIV container...
there is a attribut called "visibility" that you can set to "hidden". The DIV container hides, but where the container was ... there will be white space... is there any possibility to remove this space? because belong the container, theres text .... if the container hides, there's a gap.... I NEED TO REMOVE THIS GAP

thx for responding :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `display:none`

The difference is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: @marius ~ if that answered your question, please mark the question as answered with the green check mark :D